# Usar Virtual Hosts do Apache2 com Vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualhost

Descobri o Vagrant recentemente, e estou usando-o. Ele está bem funcional, defini um IP, instalei apache, php e cia...

Estou acessando os projetos pelo host, via localhost:8080 ou pelo IP 192.168.33.0

Porém eu quero poder acessar da mesma maneira que acessava no servidor local, via projeto1.dev, projeto2.dev, projeto3.dev, projeto4.dev...

Como acessar os projetos no Vagrant utilizando os Virtual Hosts?

Answer (score 0):

no arquivo hosts do windows 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\' adicione o IP que vc configurou no Vagrant file e o domínio que você quer.

No Apache você configura este dominio para acessar a pasta do seu projeto.

Por exemplo, vou configurar um projeto e utilizar matheusilario.mi para acessá-lo e no apache faria a seguinte configuração:

1. Na pasta /etc/apache2/sites-avaible criar o arquivo do site de acordo com a pasta do projeto em www: criei a pasta matheusilario   arquivo de configuração seria **matheusilario.conf**
2. O conteúdo deste arquivo:

   ServerName matheusilario.mi
   ServerAlias www.matheusilario.mi

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/matheusilario/

   Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All

   Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined